# Change icon in FontAwesome and Angular 10

Tags: angular, font-awesome, angular10

I got FontAwasome pro configured and working in my Angular 10 projet.

```
<div class="update-split" [class]="testClass"><fa-icon [icon]="['fad', 'sync-alt']"></fa-icon></div>
```

This line work, and display the correct icon
But If I try to bind the icon like this:

```
<div class="update-split" [class]="testClass"><fa-icon [icon]="testIcon"></fa-icon></div>
```

Then do this in my ts file

```
this.testIcon = "['fad', 'sync-alt']";
```

I got:
ERROR Error: Could not find icon with iconName=['fad', 'sync-alt'] and prefix=fas in the icon library.

So, he try to found a icon named ['fad', 'sync-alt'] in the normal fas library. Maybe is only a string with ' " error?
Thanks

Comment: Can you try giving `this.testIcon = ['fad', 'sync-alt'];` rather than in strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try replacing `this.testIcon = "['fad', 'sync-alt']";` in your ts to `this.testIcon = ['fad', 'sync-alt'];` (without the double quotes). You want to bind to an object, not to a string

Comment: Thanks! I need to change the binding property to Object too.

Answer (score -1):

it can be done by using the whole font awesome tag and class in a typescript variable such as:

```
public font_awesome:HTMLElement;
this.font_awesome  = '<i class="fas fa-adjust"></i>'
```

Then in your .html file you can bind the value as follow:

```
<span [innerHTML]="font_awesome"></span>
```

I know its not the same path as that you want to used, but hope it will help.